# How to create a View in Android like this?

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout

I am new to Android, and want to create view like this

[image: Listings Data]

This is a sample row I have created in HTML, but want to make same (or almost similar) in Android. Please guide me any way to go forward.

I wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/field_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Field 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/field_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Field 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            /* and so on */

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

but the view it gives is something like:

[image: Android view list]

Comment: I will advice to use AndroidStudio Design view if you want it the easy way
**but seriously**, the propper design of a layout is a serious topic to take care about, a propper design could relief the work of the GPU.
Take a few tutorials first, they are provided in the samples of the SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come a long way by using LinearLayout and GridLayout.
Put the first two TextViews in a LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical. 
Then put the 4 next items in a GridLayout set to 2 columns.
And the last three items with the radiobutton at the end into another LinearLayout, but with orientation set to horizontal.

EDIT:
I didn't see the two icons. It should still work with a GridLayout with 2 columns and then every second item should be a horizontal LinearLayout containing a ImageView with the icon as the source and a TextView.
You can play around with the gravity- and weight-attributes to place the views correctly.

Something close to this, although you'll have to figure out the right margin, padding and so on that works for you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Test line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Test line 2 test test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Another Test line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Test string"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Textbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Another test string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test profile link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Will I have to use Framelayout or Relativelayout on top of everything?

Comment: You can just use the FrameLayout.

Comment: I just added a xml example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Harry you can use relative  layout as a parent and inside that take linear  layout  then it becom easy.